# Microsoft Dynamics CRM “Forms for related record types” functionality is stopped working

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

My question is about SSRS report for CRM 2011 On premises version.

As everyone knows Microsoft Dynamics CRM provide us Out Of Box reports.

In these reports, there is one report named as "Invoice".
This report contains a Sub report named as "InvoiceSubReport".

The invoice report is working fine in CRM environment.

but When I am trying to run this report from Reporting server, then It is showing an error "Sub report not found".

Now, I have resolved this issue.
What I have done, I just downloaded both the reports, Opened them in BIDS, reassign the sub report to main report and uploaded in CRM.

After doing this exercise, the issue "Sub report not found" was resolved but now I am facing another issue.

The CRM "Forms for related record types" functionality is stopped working.

It means whenever I am running this report from Invoice form in CRM, It showing all the records instead of particular record.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks.